# How to create a column that has the value of another column based on the ID value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the dataframe below and I want to create a new column that has the Competitors sales growth based on the year.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'date': [2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004],  'Stock': ["GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F"], 
     'US Sales Growth': [.3, .3, .1, .1, .6, .6, .12, .12, .7, .7], 'Stock_Growth': [.1, .2, .3, .4, .14, .16,  .2, .1,.15,.16],
     'Competitor': ["F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM"] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

My goal is to have this new dataframe below

```
d = {'date': [2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004],  'Stock': ["GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F"], 
     'US Sales Growth': [.3, .3, .1, .1, .6, .6, .12, .12, .7, .7], 'Stock_Growth': [.1, .2, .3, .4, .14, .16,  .2, .1,.15,.16],
     'Competitor': ["F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM", "F", "GM"], 'Competitor_Stock_Growth': [.2, .1, .4, .3, .16, .14,  .1, .2,.16,.15]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit this question and add more details to it, the input image is not available

Comment: @Coderun sorry about that its now updated.

Comment: Thanks, can you add more details like what is formula to generate the competitor stock growth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find competitors' stocks and then merge based on `date` and `Competitor`:

```
competitor_stocks = df[['date', 'Stock', 'Stock_Growth']].rename(columns={'Stock_Growth': 'Competitor_Stock_Growth', 'Stock': 'Competitor'})
competitor_stocks
   date Competitor  Competitor_Stock_Growth
0  2000         GM                     0.10
1  2000          F                     0.20
2  2001         GM                     0.30
3  2001          F                     0.40
4  2002         GM                     0.14
5  2002          F                     0.16
6  2003         GM                     0.20
7  2003          F                     0.10
8  2004         GM                     0.15
9  2004          F                     0.16

df.merge(competitor_stocks)
   date Stock  US Sales Growth  Stock_Growth Competitor  Competitor_Stock_Growth
0  2000    GM             0.30          0.10          F                     0.20
1  2000     F             0.30          0.20         GM                     0.10
2  2001    GM             0.10          0.30          F                     0.40
3  2001     F             0.10          0.40         GM                     0.30
4  2002    GM             0.60          0.14          F                     0.16
5  2002     F             0.60          0.16         GM                     0.14
6  2003    GM             0.12          0.20          F                     0.10
7  2003     F             0.12          0.10         GM                     0.20
8  2004    GM             0.70          0.15          F                     0.16
9  2004     F             0.70          0.16         GM                     0.15
```